# Язык Си. Тема вопроса: работа с текстовыми файлами

Tags: c, файлы

Постановка задачи: найти количество гласных букв в текстовом файле (осуществить 2 возможности : чтение из созданного файла; создание нового файла, запись в него и чтение уже из этого файла). Я написал простенький код с чтением из созданного файла, но не совсем понимаю, как осуществить запись в новый файл и какой смысл перекидывать гласные в новый файл и оттуда считывать. Кто может, поясните, буду благодарен.

Код с чтением из созданного файла:

```
#include < stdio.h >

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char list[] = { 'a', 'o', 'u', 'e', 'i' };

    FILE* file = fopen("f.txt", "r");

    if (!file) 
    {
        printf("Невозможно открыть файл\n");
        return 0;
    }

    char buf[128];
    int count = 0;
    while (fgets(buf, 126, file))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 126; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(list); j++)
            {
                if (buf[i] == list[j])
                    count++;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    printf("found %d", count);
}
```

Comment: Открыть новый файл на запись -- `FILE* filew = fopen("fw.txt", "w");`

Answer (score 1):

> не совсем понимаю, как осуществить запись в новый файл и какой смысл
> перекидывать гласные в новый файл и оттуда считывать.

Вам не надо "перекидывать гласные". В задани имеется в виду, что Вы:

1. Предложите пользователю ввести произвольный текст
2. Введёте этот текст
3. Сохраните этот текст во в некотором файле
4. Обработаете только что созданный файл

Как открыть файл на запись Вам уже подсказал avp, а дальше - цикл:

1. Ввод очередной строки
2. Запись её в файл
3. Пока пользователь не нажмёт Ctrl/D (В винде - Ctrl/Z)